# Tooltip for a picture in Tableau Public

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am developing a dashboard using tableau public. My dashboard has 4 different tiles and I need to add a picture tool tip to the header of each tile. How is this achievable? Do we have anything like custom shape in tableau public?

Any sorta help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand completely but I assume that you are developing on Tableau Desktop and then publishing to Tableau Public.

Tableau's new versions are able to show sheets within tooltips, you may use this feature to show picture in your tooltip.

- First add your image to a blank sheet (credit should go to: https://community.tableau.com/thread/135563)

> 1. Copy you image file to a folder in C:\Users\\My Documents\My Tableau Repository/Shapes\My Image
>
> Note that you need to create the folder My Image
>
> 2. Create a calculated field with the formula:  `"image"`
> 3. Drag that calculate field to Rows shelf
> 4. In Marks card, select Shape
> 5. click on Shape button in Marks card and click on More Shapes....
> 6. In dialogue Edit Shape, click on Reload Shapes, then select the Shape Palette My Image and select your image as a shape
> 7. Click on OK
>
> Regulate the size of the shape on the view using Size button on Marks
>   card

- And then you may add this sheet in your tooltip using the menu below (credit should go to: https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2017/11/viz-tooltip-here-78442)

[image]